# copyright of pictures / digital signature

Tags: copyright

I am hoping to get an answer to a scenario. I have downloaded few images using Google, then clicked on the "properties" option, here, i see some of it showing details when was taken etc, and copyright by (© name of person or © getty images) however lots of images are comes up with no details at all.
Does it mean if you cannot find info who is it belongs to (i call it digital fingerprint) i can use it? how can i contact with owner to get permission to use it if i cannot find who is belongs to??

Thanks
Kristina

Comment: Hi Kristina, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean if you cannot find info who is it belongs to (i call it digital fingerprint) i can use it?

No, it does not mean that. At least not in the US. In the US, all works of art are copyrighted by default. There's no requirement that the piece has to state that it's copyrighted. The very act of having created the piece grants the creator the copyright to the work.

So, no, you can't just download images and use them for commercial work. You need to get permission first. Typically, you'd get this permission via licensing. For example, you'd go to either a photographer and hire them to take photos for you, or you'd go to a stock photo provider and purchase a license to use copies of said photos.

> how can i contact with owner to get permission to use it if i cannot find who is belongs to?

You can't. If you can't find who owns the copyright, then you can't exactly contact them to get permission.